# Async/Await inside Array#map() (Node.js, Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code for my post request in Express:

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    let value = req.body.value;

    let result = data.map(async (currentObject) => {
        return {
            nodeName: currentObject.nodeName,
            nodeStatus: await lib.checkValue(currentObject.nodeUrl, 
currentObject.nodeName, value)
        };
    });
    console.log(Promise.all(result));

    res.render('list', {data:data, value:value});
})
```

I pass the function to map asynchronously. Then I use `Promise.all` to get the result when all the promises return.

However, `Promise.all` itself returns a promise `Promise { [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ] }`

Without async, it returns the object `[ { nodeName: currentObject.nodeName, nodeStatus: Promise { <pending> }} ]`. I'd like to await when my function returns and get the `nodeStatus`.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: await Promise.all(result), async (req, res)

Comment: Why can't you `await` the `Promise.all` call? i.e. `let result = await Promise.all(data.map(async currentObj => { ... }));` As mentioned by @blackening you have to make your `app.post('/', urlEncodedParser, async (req, req) => { ... }` async too

Comment: This behavior just makes sense because `Promise.all` by itself returns a `Promise` containing the results as an array, and that `async` functions *will* return `Promise`s. Knowing this, do try `Promise.all(result).then(r => console.log(r))` instead of `console.log(Promise.all(result))` and share with us what output you get! You should be getting something like `[{nodeName: 'somename', nodeStatus: 'somestatus'}]`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Promise.all()` takes a `Promise` array and returns a `Promise`, resolving your `Promise`s and put all the resolved `Promise` results in an array. Also, we need to remember that `async` functions returns a `Promise`.

You can try running my below demo snippet:

```js
let myObj = [
  {
    foo: 'some_value',
    bar: false
  },
  {
    foo: 'some_other_value',
    bar: true
  }
]

function baz(isTrue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, isTrue ? 'TRUE!' : 'FALSE!')
  })
}

let noAsync = myObj.map(o => {
  return {
    attr1: o.foo,
    attr2: baz(o.bar)
  }
});

let promises = myObj.map(async o => {
  return {
    attr1: o.foo,
    attr2: await baz(o.bar)
  }
});

console.log('No Async :', noAsync);
console.log('Async    :', Promise.all(promises));

Promise.all(promises).then(r => console.log('Promise.then:', r));
```

P.S.: You might see `"attr2": {}` as `attr2` having an empty object when you run the snippet, but rest assured when you try it on your local machine it contains `Promise { <pending> }`